# setting a constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
ALTER TABLE Customers   
 ADD COLUMN ZipCode INT CONSTRAINT CHK_ZipCode 
 CHECK ( [ZipCode] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '[ZipCode] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')' at
> line 3

it said '[' not valid , expecting an expression

how do i solve  this?

Comment: Please write your needed result and explain it.

Comment: What MySQL version do you use? Note that `CHECK` constraints in older versions (below some 8) have no effect. They can be defined but aren't validated.

Comment: i use version 8, but i ran it already with the answer provided below by Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you would express this as:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
    ADD COLUMN ZipCode INT CONSTRAINT CHK_ZipCode CHECK (ZipCode REGEXP '^[0-9](5}$');
```

The syntax you are using looks like SQL Server.

Comment: thank you, I am using sql server;  however, i got another error saying ZipCode is violated??

Comment: i ran it like this                                                                                                                  ALTER TABLE Customers
    ADD COLUMN ZipCode INT CONSTRAINT CHK_ZipCode CHECK (ZipCode REGEXP  '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');                                                                                               and it works..thanks a lot, do you know what could have been the problem